# Expect not waiting for spawned process

Tags: expect

I'm trying to write an `expect` script to start an SSH tunnel, wait for the tunnel process to close (throwing an error) and then rerun the tunnel command. (It's worth noting that `autossh` and other automatic tunneling solutions aren't relevant here because what I'm trying to do involves `expect`.) This is the complete script with troubleshooting messages.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 1

while { $timeout == 1 } {
  spawn -noecho ssh -f -N -T -R22224:localhost:22223 username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  send_user "Looking for host"
  set timeout 0
  wait
  set timeout 1
  send_user "We've encountered an error. Re-running."
}

send_user "Out of the loop."
```

The `ssh` command works, and the [`expect` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) says that `wait` should hold the script until the current spawned process dies, but it doesn't and it ends up rerunning the loop a whole bunch of times (forcing me to `pkill` many `sshd` instances on my remote machine). I've tried `wait spawn`, `wait spawn_id`, `expect {ssh*}` (which, according to the man page, should also make the script wait), but nothing will make the script pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh -f` will fork a child process (running in background) and the parent process simply exits. Expect's `wait` command only waits for the `spawn`ed parent process so `wait` will return very soon.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing. So I just have to send the `expect` command into the background once I've verified that it's doing what I want it to. I can do that.

It's good to know that, as infuriating as the expect man page is, it was my noobish understanding of Linux processes and not my misreading of the documentation that caused the issue.